# How XCTest is loaded to process memory along with iOS App (Heap Corruption issue)?

Tags: c++, ios, heap-memory, xctest, heap-corruption

I have a quite strange crash in my XCTest suite. 
The test target is `Application tests` with `Allow testing Host Application API` checkbox enabled.
 `Build for active arch only` is YES.

Now I have only ONE test in my test suite, and it still crashes.
`Xcode` says that the cause of crash is "Heap corruption".
I've seen [the possible reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504307/2567725) of heap corruption, it seems none applies in my case.

When testing with `Address Sanitiser` and `Behaviour Sanitiser`, I get smth like this:

[image]

The test looks like this:

```
- (void)testHeapCorruption {
    MyCppClassDictionary dict;
    int file_index1 = 41;

    // MyCppClassPtr is custom_ptr<MyCppClass> 
    MyCppClassPtr data_to1 = new MyCppClass(0, 0, 41);

    dict.pushDataItem(data_to1);
        
    MyCppClassPtr data_from1 = dict.find(file_index1);
}
```

and `MyCppClass` like this:

```
typedef custom_ptr<MyCppClass> MyCppClassPtr;

MyCppClass::MyCppClass(const void* data, int len, int file_index) : m_file_index(file_index)
{
    if(len > 0)
    {
        m_data = malloc(len);
        memcpy(m_data, data, len);
    }
    
    this->m_len = len;
    m_len_initial = len;
}

MyCppClass::~MyCppClass()
{
    if (m_data) free(m_data);
}

void MyCppClassDictionary::pushDataItem(MyCppClassPtr item)
{
    assert(item);
    assert( item->m_file_index != -1 );
    m_undo_map[item->m_file_index] = item;
}

MyCppClassPtr MyCppClassDictionary::find(int file_index)
{
    auto it = m_undo_map.find(file_index);
    if ( it != m_undo_map.end() )
        return it->second;
    
    return 0;
}
```

A `custom_ptr` is a template class which works like `std::shared_ptr`: it stores the number of references to an object, and calls a destructor only when there're no references.

The crash happens only when the object code of `MyCppClass` and `MyCppClassDictionary`is located in `Application` target. When I duplicate the classes (**MyCppClass2**, **MyCppClassDictionary2**)  and link them only to `Test` target, everything is OK.

---

**Now the low-level part**

Inside `ApplicationTarget` package there's `./ApplicationTarget` binary and `PlugIns/TestTarget.xctest/./TestTarget` binary.

When see the symbols of `TestTarget` binary, `MyCppClass` functions are "extern function" in "Segment External Symbols" segment.

I assume that "Heap" in "Heap corruption" looks similar to this:

[image]

I'd like to know:

1. how exactly `TestTarget` binary is loaded into process memory, relatively to main target.
2. Is it possible that they have different heaps: one for main target, and one for test target?
3. Is it possible to debug the scenario when data is allocated on one heap, and deallocated on the other one? Inside/before the `malloc`, it is possible to print `heap`'s start address?
4. What kind of *logging* can I try? Because Address Sanitiser tells the problem post-factum.

I'd like to understand the root of the problem, but feel that my memory management/assembly skills are not enough.
Any comments/links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the problem was that the object code for Test Target and Main Target was slightly different.

A `custom_ptr` looked like this:

```
//file custom_ptr.h

template<class T> class custom_ptr
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    T* some_debug_pointer;
#endif  
};
```

And I passed `DEBUG=1` in `Preprocessor Definitions` only for Main Target.
So in Main target `custom_ptr` had a member `some_debug_pointer`, thus size of `custom_ptr` object was bigger than in Test target, where `custom_ptr` didn't have `some_debug_pointer` member.